# Como Agregar los % de cada columna con chart js

Tags: javascript, php

```
    myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ["Alimentacion","Electrica","Ventilacion"],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Correctivo',
          data: [data.resultado[0].correctivoA,data.resultado[0].correctivoE,data.resultado[0].correctivoV],
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 128, 0)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255)',
          borderWidth: 2,
          stack: 'Stack 0'
        }, {
          label: 'Preventivo',
          data: [data.resultado[0].preventivoA,data.resultado[0].preventivoE,data.resultado[0].preventivoV],
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,255)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255)',
          borderWidth: 2,
          stack: 'Stack 0'
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Solo necesito agregar texto dentro de las columnas**

No encuentro la manera de agregar el texto dentro de cada columna ya que cada columna se separa en dos y necesito poner textos por separados

Comment: Y para eso necesitas usar una librería de terceros cuando se puede hacer ese diseño solo con html y css? Si quieres agregar texto via js, usa innerHTML. Por cierto, te recomendaría suavizar un poco los colores. Sobre todo el azul (que parece un #0000ff) y el fondo negro

Comment: @Xedrian No tiene sentido lo que señalas

Comment: @Xedrian o `textContent`.

Comment: Bienvenido, revisar [ask], agrega lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, saludos.

Answer (score -1):

El texto dentro de los bars como tal no podrás meterlo, pero si podrás mostrar el dato del porcentaje mediante un tooltips. Por lo tanto dentro del options tendrás que añadir una propiedad que se llame tooltips.

Te adjunto el link de un ejemplo:

https://codepen.io/k3no/pen/OReEKx?editors=0010

Comment: Revisar [answer]

Answer (score -2):

Tienes que usar el pluggin [datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/), donde una configuración posible sería agregar en `options`

```
plugins: {
    datalabels: {
    color: "white",
    anchor: 'center',
    align: 'center',
    formatter: function(value, context) { // Esto es solo para agregar el caractaer "%" luego del valor
        return value + ' %';
    },
    font: {
        weight: 'bold',
    }
}
```

Ejemplo:

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
var ctx = document.getElementById("articulos").getContext('2d');
var ventas = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Alimentacion","Electrica","Ventilacion"],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Correctivo',
          data:[42,34,54],
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 128, 0)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255)',
          borderWidth: 2,
          stack: 'Stack 0'
        }, {
          label: 'Preventivo',
          data:[24,44,34],
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,255)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255)',
          borderWidth: 2,
          stack: 'Stack 0'
        }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
          y: {
              beginAtZero: true
          }
      },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
       color: "white",
        anchor: 'center',
        align: 'center',
        formatter: function(value, context) {
           return value + ' %';
        },
        font: {
          weight: 'bold',
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="box-body mx-auto">
  <canvas id="articulos" width="100" height="30"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
```

Comment: Ayudanos a mantener la calidad de la información en el sitio, respondiendo a preguntas realizadas de acuerdo a [ask] saludos.